# Hp Proliant ML350 G6 Fan 1 Missing

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, hp-proliant, fan

HP proliant ML350 G6, 2 fans were working (Fan 1 & 2), all of a sudden fan 1 spoilt after 2 years, bought a new fan, new fan wont work on fan 1 slot but works on other slots and without fan 1 system wont come on, keeps saying fan 1 missing

Comment: Have you tried putting fan 2 in fan 1 slot?

Answer (score 2):

If you plug fan2 into fan1's slot and it still doesn't work, it's not fan1 that is broken but the fan slot. The ml350 g6 is a pretty old model (7 years) so it's due for retirement anyway. Replace it with a working server.

Answer (score 1):

Try firmware, if possible... There were false system board and fan controller errors on this platform.

Of course, swap fans and see if the issue follows the fan or the slot.

Worst case, it's a system board. Best case, it's just an issue with the fan header or something that can be solved via software or a long power-off/on cycle (remove the power plugs).

Answer (score 1):

i have switched fans, tried the fan on all the other slots, they're working but not working in fan 1, and fan 1 seems to b the very important one it cant do without, because of that server keeps giving the error